Restar dos fechas en la misma columna en sql
Tengo una serie de registros identificados por un ID, cada ID tiene dos fechas que se encuentran en la misma columna, necesito sacar la diferencia entre las dos fechas por ID.



ID.
Proceso.
Fecha




Id1
Inicio.
12-09-2024-05:05:06


Id1
Final.
12-09-2024-05:07:00


Id2
Inicio.
11-09-2024-11:00:00


Id2
Final.
11-09-2024-11:00:00



He probado con timestamdiff y LAG, pero me resta la fecha del ID 2 a la fecha del ID 1, y pues no me sale el tiempo correcto
Gracias por la ayuda q me puedan dar

Seria buena idea colocar el motor de base de datos que estas utilizando. Saludos.

Unis la tabla a si misma por el id, y luego restas los dos campos..

Basicamente lo que te comentó @gbianchi, JOIN de la tabla consigo misma pareando las filas de inicio y final.
select  I.ID,
        DATEDIFF(F.Fecha, I.Fecha) AS 'DiferenciaDias'
        FROM Tabla I
        INNER JOIN Tabla F
              ON F.ID = I.ID
              AND F.Proceso = 'Final.'
        WHERE I.Proceso = 'Inicio.'

Por lo que comentas, pareciera ser mysql por lo que puedes usar DATEDIFF() para obtener la diferencia de días. Importante: esta consulta es efectiva en caso que las filas sean consistentes, es decir cada ID tenga un único Inicio y Final, en caso que no hubiera un Final simplemente modifica le INNER por un LEFT.

Para realizar esto, existen varias formas a nivel de codígo para hacerlo, te muestro una de ellas.
SELECT t2.id, DATEDIFF(MONTH, FECHAINICIO, FECHAFINAL ) AS DIFERENCIAMES
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ID,
        (SELECT Fecha AS F1 FROM SOVER WHERE id = t1.ID AND Proceso = 'inicio') AS FECHAINICIO, 
        (SELECT TOP 1 Fecha AS F1 FROM SOVER WHERE t1.id = ID AND Proceso = 'fin') AS FECHAFINAL
    FROM [SOVER] t1
) T2

Lo primero que realizo es una consulta, donde recuperé la fecha de inicio, cuando el proceso sea inició o bien fin
    (SELECT Fecha AS F1 FROM SOVER WHERE id = t1.ID AND Proceso = 'inicio') AS FECHAINICIO, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 Fecha AS F1 FROM SOVER WHERE t1.id = ID AND Proceso = 'fin') AS FECHAFINAL

y a su vez, concuerde con el id de la primera consulta en donde obtuvimos unicamente los ids de manera unica, de ahí utilizar el DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ID,
    (SELECT Fecha AS F1 FROM SOVER WHERE id = t1.ID AND Proceso = 'inicio') AS FECHAINICIO, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 Fecha AS F1 FROM SOVER WHERE t1.id = ID AND Proceso = 'fin') AS FECHAFINAL
FROM [SOVER] t1

posteriormente, la consulta resultante la utilizo como una tabla y apartir de ahí, con el DATEDIFF puedes obtener en meses, años o días, depende de tu necesidad la diferencia entre las fechas.
Importante recalcar que la tabla SOVER es una tabla que creé para realizar el ejemplo, ahí deberás de poner el nombre que tenga tu tabla con los datos.
Espero el ejemplo te sea de ayuda.
Saludos.

Te dejo 2 opciones para hacerlo.
Primero creamos los datos de prueba sobre los que podemos trabajar.
CREATE TABLE Prueba(
    ID  varchar(10),
    Proceso varchar(10),
    Fecha   datetime);
INSERT INTO Prueba
VALUES
( 'Id1', 'Inicio', '20240912 05:05:06'),
( 'Id1', 'Final ', '20240912 05:07:00'),
( 'Id2', 'Inicio', '20240911 11:00:00'),
( 'Id2', 'Final ', '20240911 11:00:15');

Ahora, para el primer ejemplo uso algo que llamo agregado condicional para convertir filas en columnas. Eso lo incluyo en un CTE y así puedo hacer referencia a los nombres de las columnas sin problema para obtener la diferencia en segundos y lo muestro como un tipo time.
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ID,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Proceso = 'Inicio' THEN Fecha END) AS Inicio,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Proceso = 'Final ' THEN Fecha END) AS Final
    FROM Prueba
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT ID,
    Inicio,
    Final,
    DATEADD( SS, DATEDIFF( SS, Inicio, Final), CAST( '00:00' AS time)) AS diferencia
FROM CTE;

Para el segundo caso, utilizo la función LAG y me aseguro de que se reinicie correctamente. Sin embargo, aquí tengo que descartar la mitad de las filas del resultado que no me interesan.
WITH CTE2 AS(
    SELECT ID,
        LAG( Fecha) OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IIF( Proceso = 'Inicio', 1, 2)) AS Inicio,
        Fecha AS Final
    FROM Prueba
)
SELECT ID,
    Inicio,
    Final,
    DATEADD( SS, DATEDIFF( SS, Inicio, Final), CAST( '00:00' AS time)) AS diferencia
FROM CTE2
WHERE Inicio IS NOT NULL;

Personalmente, recomiendo la primer opción ya que es la que menos trabajo realiza para generar el resultado. A diferencia de la respuesta de Patricio, solo necesita leer la tabla una vez.
El único problema que pueden tener estas soluciones es si no tienes el par de forma adecuada. Ya sea que haya solo una fila o más de 2.
